# How can I remove rows containing specific value, on a scalable way?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
Column_A    Column_B    Column_C

 10          Total        20
 20           10          20
 30           15          10
 Total        98         Total
```

I would like to remove all rows, containing 'Total'.

In my real case, **I have many columns**. Therefore, I am **not looking for this solution**:

```
df[df['Column_A'] != 'Total'] 
df[df['Column_B'] != 'Total'] 
df[df['Column_C'] != 'Total']
```

Instead, I would like to have a solution to **check for all columns.**

The proposed outcome should be:

```
Column_A    Column_B    Column_C

 20           10          20
 30           15          10
```

Comment: Where does the data come from? Maybe consider marking `Total` as an NA value at ingestion - and dropping rows with NA, if that is possible with your data.  One benefit: Numerical types will be in place already. Otherwise you'll have to convert later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with help of [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html), [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and the boolean NOT operator `~`.

If any value is the row is equal to Total, do not index it.

```
out = df[~df.eq('Total').any(axis=1)]
```

output:

```
  Column_A Column_B Column_C
1       20       10       20
2       30       15       10
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the another solution but this is not much optimal for larger data.

```
for column in df.columns:
   df = df[df[column]!='Total']
```